# Consume single json but publish multiple AVRO messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to Spring kafka  Stream. I recently setup a project and tried kafka stream APIs to publish AVRO.
Requirement:
Need to parse a complex Jsonobject which might have multple sub jsons. Parse the json and send out AVRO message for each sub Json. It can be one or more also.

I know how to do this with kafka client APIs. Its easy and can be done with Loop but with Stream API, I am new.

Current Code for stream class is like this below :

```
@Service
@Log4j2
@EnableBinding(StreamBindings.class)
public class StreamListener {

    @Autowired
    Service service; 
    
    @StreamListener("Processor-input-channel")
    @SendTo("Processor-output-channel")
    public KStream<String, AVROClass> process(KStream<String, String> input){
        //parse input , map to fault and change received key to time stamp and send 
        KStream<String, AVROClass> kStream = input
                .mapValues(v -> service.getAVROResponse(v))
                .map((k,v)->KeyValue.pair((Long.toString((System.currentTimeMillis()))), v));

        kStream.foreach((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s", k, v)));
        
        
        return kStream;
        
    }
```

I am generating one AVRO at a time but I need to know how I can generate multiple AVROs and send out to output topic as separate messages in kafka.As what ever I return from getAVROResponse will be sent out by stream automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To consume JSON, you'd need to use a String/JSON Serde, not `AvroClass` (assuming this actually is an Avro `SpecificRecord` subclass).

Otherwise, you seem to be missing the Avro Serde, `Consumed.with(<<avroSerde>>))`, or set this as your default serde in the StreamsConfig

If you want to separate the incoming message, to several different topics based on some condition (your nested types) use `branch`

If you want to take one message to several messages, and then to some output topic, use `flatMapValues().to()`

And to produce Avro, be sure to use `Produced.with()` in the `.to()` output

Comment: So i am not separating incoming message into different topic but instead receiving one message and sending multiple messages for the same message on one topic

Comment: Sure, as answered, [you want `flatMap`](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this use case using Kafka Streams and Spring Cloud Stream as below. Please note that the usage of `StreamListener` is no longer recommended and suggest going with the functional approach. See below.

This is just a psuedo-code and please update as necessary.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, AvroClass>> process() {
        return input -> input.mapValues(v -> service.getAVROResponse(v))
                .map((k,v)->KeyValue.pair((Long.toString((System.currentTimeMillis()))), v));
    }

    @Bean
    public Serde<AvroClass> avroInSerde(){
        final SpecificAvroSerde<AvroClass> avroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        avroSerde.configure(...)
        return avroInSerde;
    }

}
```

In the configuration, you need this depending on your setup. Please update the schema registry URL appropriately.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
              specific.avro.reader: true
```

If you don't want to specify the Avro serde as a Spring bean as above, you can configure this as below instead.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-out-0.producer.valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

However, I think specifying the avro serde as a Spring bean might be a cleaner approach as the Spring Cloud Stream binder can do a type match for the function signature against the Serde bean's type. For example, in this case, the binder will introspect the function and match it's output signature - `KStream<String, AvroClass>` - with what is defined on the Serde bean - `Serde<AvroClass>` - and assign that as the value Serde on the outbound.

Comment: I have a doubt here @sobychako , I see that here pseudo code accepts single message and returns single message which has value type as AVRO Class. My requirement is to return multiple messages which will be more like a list of  AVROClasses or multiple messages published as AVRO. But I feel the pseudo code wont do that

Comment: Is the signature something like this? `Function<KStream<String, List<String>>, KStream<String, List<AvroClass>>>`

Comment: Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, List<AvroClass>>>, application input is single json always but there is a scenario where that json can jave subjsons and i need to parse them into multiple avros and publish